# needing help to simulate an xhr request

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, scrapy

I need to scrape a website with a "load more button". This is my spider code written in Python:

```
import scrapy
import json
import requests
import re
from parsel import Selector
from scrapy.selector import Selector 
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

headers = {
'origin': 'https://www.tayara.tn',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'accept': '*/*',
'referer': 'https://www.tayara.tn/sc/immobilier/bureaux-et-plateaux',
'authority': 'www.tayara.tn',
'dnt': '1',
}
data = '{"query":"query ListingsPage($page: Page, $filter: SearchFilter, $sortBy: SortOrder) {\\n  listings: searchAds(page: $page, filter: $filter, sortBy: $sortBy) {\\n    items {\\n      uuid\\n      title\\n      price\\n      currency\\n      thumbnail\\n      createdAt\\n      category {\\n        id\\n        name\\n        engName\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      user {\\n        uuid\\n        displayName\\n        avatar(width: 96, height: 96) {\\n          url\\n          __typename\\n        }\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    trackingInfo {\\n      transactionId\\n      listName\\n      recommenderId\\n      experimentId\\n      variantId\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    totalCount\\n    pageInfo {\\n      startCursor\\n      hasPreviousPage\\n      endCursor\\n      hasNextPage\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n}\\n","variables":{"page":{"count":36,"offset":"cDEwbg==.MjAxOC0xMi0wMlQxMzo1MDoxMlo=.MzY="},"filter":{"queryString":null,"category":"140","regionId":null,"attributeFilters":[]},"sortBy":"CREATED_DESC"},"operationName":"ListingsPage"}'

class Tun(scrapy.Spider):

name="tayaracommercial"
start_urls = [
    'https://www.tayara.tn/sc/immobilier/bureaux-et-plateaux'
    ]

def parse(self, response):        
    yield Request('https://www.tayara.tn/graphql', method='post', headers=headers, body=data, self.parse_item)


def parse_item(self, response):

    source = 'Tayara'        
    reference = response.url.split('//')[1].split('/')[3]
    titre = response.xpath('//h1[@data-name="adview_title"]/text()').extract()   

    yield{'Source':source, 'Reference':reference, 'Titre':titre}
```

This is my modest trial. I know that is false. can you correct me please ?

Comment: XHR request is normal request with header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` (wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). But some servers don't check it and you can do normal request. You need only url for this request. You can find it in HTML using XPath. Or you can use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to see all requests send from browser to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape data with following example:

```
# Importing the dependencies
# This is needed to create a lxml object that uses the css selector
 from lxml.etree import fromstring
  
# The requests library
import requests
  
class WholeFoodsScraper:
  
  API_url = 'http://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/views/ajax'
    scraped_stores = []

    def get_stores_info(self, page):
     
        # This is the only data required by the api 
        # To send back the stores info
        data = {
        'view_name': 'store_locations_by_state',
        'view_display_id': 'state',
        'page': page
        }
        # Making the post request
        response = requests.post(self.API_url, data=data)

        # The data that we are looking is in the second
        # Element of the response and has the key 'data', 
        # so that is what's returned
        return response.json()[1]['data']
```