# How can I scrape this website knowing that I used selenium, splash, mimic xhr request and I failed

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I need to scrape this [website](https://www.tayara.tn/sc/immobilier/appartements) which is with a "load more" button.

1. I used selenium but execution time was too long and I failed to scrape all needed items.
2. I used splash but I didn't get any result
3. I tried to simulate XHR requests and I failed also

What tools are suitable to scrape such a website ?

Comment: You can try https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: My recommendation is at least to add the code you tried, and the issues you encountered, to avoid close votes, as asking for a tool is off-topic on SO.

Comment: here is my trial to simulate an XHR request that failed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54171736/needing-help-to-simulate-an-xhr-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's make clear how does the downloading process of new portions of items work. In a browser, e. g. Chrome, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open DevTools, navigate to https://www.tayara.tn/sc/immobilier/appartements, scroll down, and make a few new items loadings, go to Network tab, set the filter to XHR, it will look like as shown below:

[image: Network tab]

You may notice each time you click "Montrer plus" button, the new request with size about 5 KB is logged. There are all the necessary data in the response:

[image: XHR response]

To make such XHR you need to retrieve `data.listings.pageInfo.endCursor` value from the previous response, and put it as `variables.page.offset` property into the request payload, of course, you need to keep the entire payload structure also, and add the relevant headers:

[image: XHR request]

Regarding `variables.page.offset` property. Actually, it consists of three Base64 encoded parts, after decoding it's obvious that e. g. `cDEwbg==.MjAxOS0wMS0yNlQyMDoyMTo1OFo=.NjAwMA==` is some prefix `p10n` + start date `2019-01-26T20:21:58Z` + total retrieved items `6000`. So you may request any other portion of items by changing the last one value. Also, you may specify the amount of items per request in `variables.page.count` property (seems the limit is 100).

Here is VBA example showing how such scraping could be done. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim sCat As String
    Dim oResSht As Worksheet
    Dim oResCell As Range
    Dim lNextOutput As Long
    Dim sOffset As String
    Dim oRes As Object
    Dim sPayload As String
    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aItems
    Dim oItem

    ' Set category for parsing
    sCat = "2"
    ' Set output sheet
    Set oResSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    With oResSht
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        Set oResCell = .Cells(1, 1)
    End With
    lNextOutput = 1000
    sOffset = ""
    Set oRes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Do
        ' Retrieve JSON content
        sPayload = _
            "{""query"":""query ListingsPage($page: Page, $filter: SearchFilter, $sortBy: SortOrder) {\n  listings: searchAds(page: $page, filter: $filter, sortBy: $sortBy) " & _
            "{\n    items {\n      uuid\n      title\n      price\n      currency\n      thumbnail\n      createdAt\n      state\n      category " & _
            "{\n        id\n        name\n        engName\n        __typename\n      }\n      user {\n        uuid\n        displayName\n        avatar(width: 96, height: 96) " & _
            "{\n          url\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    trackingInfo " & _
            "{\n      transactionId\n      listName\n      recommenderId\n      experimentId\n      variantId\n      __typename\n    }\n    totalCount\n    pageInfo " & _
            "{\n      startCursor\n      hasPreviousPage\n      endCursor\n      hasNextPage\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n""," & _
            """variables"":{""page"":{""count"":100,""offset"":""" & sOffset & """},""filter"":{""queryString"":null,""category"":""" & sCat & """,""regionId"":null,""attributeFilters"":[]},""sortBy"":""CREATED_DESC""},""operationName"":""ListingsPage""}"
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "POST", "https://www.tayara.tn/graphql", True
            .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json"
            '.setRequestHeader "user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
            .setRequestHeader "content-length", Len(sPayload)
            .send (sPayload)
            Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            sJSONString = .responseText
        End With
        ' Parse JSON sample
        JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
        Select Case True
            Case sState <> "Object"
                Debug.Print Now & " Invalid JSON response"
            Case IsNull(vJSON("data"))
                Debug.Print Now & " Response contains no data"
            Case Else
                ' Retrieve items
                aItems = vJSON("data")("listings")("items")
                ' Add retrieved items to resulting dataset
                For Each oItem In aItems
                    Set oRes(oRes.Count) = oItem
                Next
                ' Check if the page is last
                If vJSON("data")("listings")("pageInfo")("hasNextPage") = False Then Exit Do
                ' Retrieve offset property for next page request
                sOffset = vJSON("data")("listings")("pageInfo")("endCursor")
                Debug.Print Now & " " & sOffset
                ' Output once per 1000 parsed items
                If oRes.Count >= lNextOutput Then
                    Output oRes, oResCell
                    lNextOutput = oRes.Count + 1000
                End If
        End Select
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ' Finally output results
    Output oRes, oResCell
    MsgBox "Completed" & vbCrLf & "Actually parsed: " & oRes.Count & vbCrLf & """totalCount"" from API response: " & vJSON("data")("listings")("totalCount")

End Sub

Sub Output(vData, oTarget As Range)

    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    ' Convert raw JSON to 2d array and output to target range
    JSON.ToArray vData, aData, aHeader
    With oTarget
        OutputArray oTarget.Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray oTarget.Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0), aData
        .Parent.Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

The output for me is as follows:

[image: output]

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).

Comment: I'm really in short of time and I need this ASAP and I am not familiar with VBA. Can you tell me please what I need to execute this VBA code on my windows 10 ?

Comment: @user3729357 You need MS Office, i. e. Excel. That algorithm could be easily adopted for javascript and launched even in the browser console.

Comment: It worked fine for five other URLs from the same website (I changed only "category" value) but it doesn't work for these URLs: https://www.tayara.tn/sc/immobilier/locations-de-vacances and https://www.tayara.tn/sc/immobilier/autre-immobilier and https://www.tayara.tn/sc/immobilier/colocations. I must modify other parameters ?

Comment: @user3729357 Check update please, I fixed output algorithm.